# Robust control (H infinity) is H for Hilbert?

Tags: control-theory

I wanted to know if the 'H' in 'H infinity' stands for Hilbert ?
Thank you

Comment: The spaces $H^{\infty}$ in Complex Analysis are named after Hardy.

Answer (score 1):

In control theory $H_{\infty}$ is the Hardy space of matrix-valued functions that are analytic and bounded in the open half plane $\{ s \in \mathbb C: Re(s) >0\}.$